# How to register cypress `code-coverage` plugin with cypress v10?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, cypress, cypress-code-coverage

In [cypress migration guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Plugins-File-Removed) they mention that plugin files are no longer supported. They also mention that [you need to use >=v3.10 of `code-coverage` plugin](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Code-Coverage-Plugin)

I do have correct version installed, and I tried to update `cypress.config.ts` to:

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  video: false,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config)
      return config
    },
  },
});
```

but it doesn't work. What's the correct way? I believe I do have instrumenting working (I'm using `@cypress/instrument-cra` and see **coverage** object) but I don't see generated coverage files and I don't see a reset coverege step in tests

Comment: Your setup looks different from what the [guide](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#install) recommends to install the plugin.

Comment: yes, because I believe the readme wasn't updated to work with cypress v10. Anyway doing what this guide recommends also doesn't work for me

Comment: Indeed, that guide has not been updated but the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Install-the-plugin) have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description the only step missing is the support file import.

```js
// cypress/support/e2e.js
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
```

I also have a `.babelrc` with the following, but I believe you can do without it if just covering e2e tests.

```js
{
  "plugins": ["istanbul"]
}
```

Let me know if that's not it, I will give you step-by-step.

Comment: Yes, that's actually it. I had import statement in file `support/index.js` following something outdated, moving it into `e2e.js` fixed it. Thanks!